# unable to see my JavaScript code on browser

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, browser

I am new in programming. Working on Javascript and using visual studio for coding. When I learn HTML I was able to see my work on a browser. I do not know how to do it for Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to unable the JavaScript source Map on Ur browser configuration ? To Check it, click on F12 => settings => Preferences => Enable JavaScript source map.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to see on the browser ? your javascript code will be executed by your browser to add functionality on your web page, adding events on html elements, networking functionalities, and other goodies. it not something you see, is more of something you feel

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a programing language you have to use it with HTML to make it work. Javascript only adds functionality to your HTML code it does not gives you any visual structure. For more you can refer to this link:-

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: Thank you very much. My understanding is, I have you write Javascript code inside of HTML ?

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: just go for the above link if you are new to javascript.

Comment: Deeply Appreciate

Comment: if you my answer is useful to you.. please hit the tick on the anser

Comment: if you find my answer useful hit the tick button on my answer.